# Doctrine SQL Server uniqueidentifier isn't cast as char or nvarchar when retrieved from the database

Tags: php, sql-server, doctrine, uniqueidentifier, null-uniqueidentifier

When I retrieve a record from the database which has a column of type "uniqueidentifier", Doctrine fills it with "null" rather than the unique id from the database.

Some research and testing has brought this down to a PDO/dblib driver issue. When directly querying via PDO, null is returned in place of the unique id.

For reference, http://trac.doctrine-project.org/ticket/1096, has a bit on this, however, it was updated 11 months ago with no comment for resolution.

A way around this, as mentioned at http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=24752&edit=1, is to cast the column as a char. However, it doesn't seem Doctrine exposes the native field type outside of generating models which makes it a bit hard to detect uniqueidentifier types and cast them internally when building the sql query.

Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I submitted a patch for this, fix is in PHP 5.3.7 and later.  See this bug report for further info http://bugs.php.net/54167

As of PHP 5.3.7 it will return the uniqueidentifier as a string which will work fine with Doctrine 1 & 2.

In my case, I also needed to specify the tds version in freetds.conf to properly receive the uniqueidentifier value as a string.  The tds version that worked for me (which is probably specific to the SQL server version I am communicating with) is "tds version = 7.0"

Comment: Epic find, my friend. Unfortunately, I've opted not to use Doctrine for many reasons, this being a minor one in comparison to the others.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 fixes for PHP, [Bug #54167](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54167) resolves the NULL problem with dblib.  Unfortunately, when it was merged into PHP, another bug caused another problem with unique identifiers which corrupted them.  Basically, they'd lose the lower bits (filling them in with zeroes like E3407588-2B77-0000-0200-000000000000).  [There is a bug fix](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=60033), but it won't come out until PHP 5.4 .

The general solution is to cast the uniqueidentifer as a string, but Doctrine doesn't handle this.  A simple patch for Doctrine involves changing the column definition from a `string(36)` to a `guid`, then having Doctrine do the cast for you in the Query.php file.  A sample would be:

```
// In the schema file
columns:
  userid:
    type: guid
    fixed: false
    unsigned: false
    notnull: false
    primary: true
    autoincrement: false

// Which generates this in the base model
$this->hasColumn('userid', 'guid', null, array(
         'type' => 'guid',
         'fixed' => 0,
         'unsigned' => false,
         'notnull' => false,
         'primary' => true,
         'autoincrement' => false,
));

// Only after you change this in Doctrine/DataDict/Mssql.php on line 192-194
case 'uniqueidentifier':
    $type[] = 'guid'; // changed from 'string'
    $length = 36;

// Then to use the new guid datatype, edit Doctrine/Query.php starting on line 487
foreach ($fields as $fieldName) {
        $columnName = $table->getColumnName($fieldName);
        if (($owner = $table->getColumnOwner($columnName)) !== null &&
                $owner !== $table->getComponentName()) {

            $parent = $this->_conn->getTable($owner);
            $columnName = $parent->getColumnName($fieldName);
            $parentAlias = $this->getSqlTableAlias($componentAlias . '.' . $parent->getComponentName());
            $sql[] = $this->_conn->quoteIdentifier($parentAlias) . '.' . $this->_conn->quoteIdentifier($columnName)
                   . ' AS '
                   . $this->_conn->quoteIdentifier($tableAlias . '__' . $columnName);
        } else {
            /* This new code will get the column definition, look for guid, then cast the column as a string to work around PHP bug 60033.  Everything above this line is unchanged */
            $columnName = $table->getColumnName($fieldName);

            $columnDefinition = $table->getColumnDefinition($columnName);

            if ($columnDefinition['type'] == 'guid') {
                $sql[] = 'CAST(' . $this->_conn->quoteIdentifier($tableAlias) . '.' . $this->_conn->quoteIdentifier($columnName) . ' as VARCHAR(36))'
                   . ' AS '
                   . $this->_conn->quoteIdentifier($tableAlias . '__' . $columnName);

            } else {
                    // this block is unchanged from the original
                $sql[] = $this->_conn->quoteIdentifier($tableAlias) . '.' . $this->_conn->quoteIdentifier($columnName)
                   . ' AS '
                   . $this->_conn->quoteIdentifier($tableAlias . '__' . $columnName);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure if you need to add the same code above in the first part of the IF statement, but I added this code and now all my unique identifiers come back correctly (with the lower part  not zeroes like E3407588-2B77-0000-0276-3D9E8DE868D6).  Maybe the guys in Doctrine will add this patch in, since Doctrine is useless with SQL Server's unique identifiers with any version of PHP<5.4.

And I know that editing the Doctrine code by hand is not recommended, but this was after I tried running PHP 5.4 beta2 from source and spending hours trying to get the newer sqlsrv driver to work in Doctrine 1.2.  Besides, these lines of code are a lot easier than re-writing all my queries using the older mssql_query code.

Hope this helps.